# Cloud Functions: Realtime Database transaction not working with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to decrease the field `amount` which represents the amount of products available for sale.

My database is structured like below:

```
- Stock
 - StoreId
  - DepartmentId
   - ProductId
    + price
    + amount
```

My `storeId` has a fixed value and I am only looping through the variables `DepartmentId` and `ProductId`.

Below is how I created a node array or children array for the **transaction**:

```
  const childArray = [];
  depIds.forEach(depId => {
    const prodIds = groupedProducts[depId].reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val.prodId], []);
    prodIds.forEach(prodId => {

      childArray.push(admin.database().ref("Stock")
        .child(storeId)
        .child(depId)
        .child(prodId)
        .child("amount")
        .once('value'));
    });
  });
```

When I add the condition: `amount > 0`, nothing happens. It only works when I remove the condition.

```
const snapshots = await Promise.all(childArray);
snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
  snapshot.ref.transaction(amount => {
    //if (amount) return amount + admin.database.ServerValue.increment(-1);
    if (amount > 0) return amount - 1;
        
  })
})
```

**Furthermore, what I really need is to compare the amount in the database with the amount coming from the request (let's call it qty)**

For this, I would have to retrieve the current path for `productId` and `departmentId`. But as showed below, snapshot.ref.parent does not return the path.

```
snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
  snapshot.ref.transaction(amount => {
    //if (amount > 0 & amount >= qty) return amount + admin.database.ServerValue.increment(-qty);

    const productPath = snapshot.ref.parent;
    const departmentPath = snapshot.ref.parent.parent;
    // Get qty based on productPath and departmentPath
    if (amount > 0 & amount >= qty) return amount - qty;
        
  })
})
```

So, I have three questions:

1. How to retrieve the current paths for departmentId and productId
2. How to update the field amount based on a condition and abort the whole transaction if any condition is not satisfied
3. How to make admin.database.ServerValue.increment(-qty) work

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a transaction for this. Instead, once you know the full path of the node(s) to update, you can [use `increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) and then use security rules to [validate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules) that the value doesn't go below 0.

So in code that'd be:

```
admin.database().ref("Stock")
  .child(storeId)
  .child(depId)
  .child(prodId)
  .update({ "amount", admin.database.ServerValue.increment(-1));
```

And then in the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Stock": {
      "$storeId": {
        "$depId": {
          "$prodId": {
            "amount": {
              ".validate": "newData.val() >= 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the case of concurrent writings for subtraction, would `update` be an issue? Because many users can write this field at the same time.

Comment: Even if multiple users all fire the `increment(-1)` in rapid succession, the security rules (which execute on the database server) will prevent any of them from making the `amount` negative.

Comment: The validation `".validate": "newData.val() >= 0"` is not preventing the field `amount` to go negative numbers. How to solve it?

Comment: That is unexpected. Did you check the documentation link I included about validating in security rules? Does the rule make sense and look correct after reading that?  How did you test? Did you try to get the same results in the rules playground?

Comment: Yes, I checked the documentation and the validation looks OK to me. But for some reason, the validation allows the field `amount` to go to negative numbers. I couldn't find a solution in the documentation.

Comment: It is really unexpected! In the rules playground it refuses the writing operation as expected, but the update is with a json object `{"amount": -1}`. I do not know if it has something to do with `increment(-1)` coming from the cloud functions.

Comment: Oh yes, that explains. If you use an Admin SDK (as you usually do in Cloud Functions), the calls bypass all security rules. Sorry for overlooking that in my answer. If you want you can set a specific UID in the SDK instance as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#accessing_user_authentication_information

Comment: In my case, I am using an express endpoint to do the updating operation and the user authentication is checked with a middleware. If the user is authenticated he/she can do the subtraction of the `amount` field, but it must not go to negative numbers. How could I apply the last link you suggested to the solution?